# I see you have finished vs I see you finished

Tags: present-tense, present-simple

My question may sound stupid because I know when we are using it but I don't know how to explain it by words.

`have finished` means that something will end soon or later like `when you have finished your test give it back to me`

and

`you finished` means that something already ended and has no continuation

Am I right and I just answered my question or I made a mistake somewhere in my way of thinking? hah

Comment: "have" is also used when something has finished, in the recent past. Have you studied tenses yet? Look at the use of present perfect and simple past tense. Your first example is future tense.

Answer (score 1):

Tenses and conditionals are one of the most complex issues in English grammar

> When you have finished the test, hand it in to me

is effectively referring to the future despite the names of the tenses.

It is an emphatic version of

> When you finish the test, hand it in to me

which also refers to the future. But instead of thinking so closely about the clock, think about aspect and dependency. You are to hand it in only **after* you have **completed** the test. From the time relative to handing that test in, completion **precedes** it.

What the names of tenses are and how they are used in non-conditional contexts will not help you understand them in the context of conditionals.

The problem is that we think of conditionals as being introduced by "if." In the context of the future, "when" may never occur. You may never finish the test because it is so absurdly hard, you have a heart attack and die. So, in many contexts "when" actually means "if and when."